# org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

Getting Eclipse Error - when Switching from editor to console(Any View, like Logs, Package Window) and coming back to editor view.

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:718)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.createHandle(Label.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:758)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.<init>(Label.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusLineContributionItem.fill(StatusLineContributionItem.java:165)
```

My eclipse Config is:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200
OS: Windows 7, v.6.1, x86_64 / win32

and I already installed WindowBuilder and have made its editor default - and search on internet as well - but no success in solving it.

Comment: From the stacktrace we can see that Windows refuses to create a new widget because of exhausted handles. The most probable reason I suppose is that a program that is running outside Eclipse has created too many windows or has a resource leakage. May be it is your own program hat you run from Eclipse. Make sure that all the system resources you use (fonts, colors, dialogs,etc.) are properly disposed. Close all irrelevant applications. Restart Windows. If none of these helps, try to install a new instance of Eclipse.

Comment: I get this error after installing spring tool suite plugin(sts)